# How to apply foverlaps when the small interval is in the wrong table

Tags: r, join, data.table, overlap

I'm trying to apply a merge using foverlaps as part of my set up to run rolling regression on various subsets.

### Set Up

The set up is as follows:
DT1 includes two unique identifiers (gvkey, iid), set portfolio rebalancing dates (RDt), and a bunch of subset dummy variables based on previous calculations/rankings.

DT2 includes a full list of daily stock returns for each gvkey and iid combination

```
DT1 <- data.table(gvkey = rep(LETTERS[1:20],20), 
                  RDt = rep(ymd("1998-06-30") + years(0:19),each=20), 
                  indicator_1 = sample(0:1,400,replace = TRUE), 
                  indicator_k = sample(0:1,400,replace = TRUE))
DT2 <- data.table(gvkey = rep(LETTERS[1:20],20,length.out=7275),
                  datadate = seq(ymd("1998-01-30"), ymd("2017-12-30"), by="days"), 
                  log_ret = rlnorm(7275))
#Note for laziness I have left weekends in and have excluded second identifier (iid)
```

I am wanting to replicate all dummy variables in DT1 into DT2 based on a 6 month window around RDt, such that, given:

```
DT1[gvkey=="A" & RDt =="1998-06-30"]

   gvkey        RDt indicator_1 indicator_k
1:     A 1998-06-30           1           0
```

The subset of the merged table (DT3):

```
DT3[gvkey=="A" & between(datadate,"1998-01-01", "1998-06-30")]
```

Results in something similar to the output of:

```
DT3 <- data.table(gvkey = rep("A",181), "datadate" = seq(ymd("1998-01-01"), ymd("1998-06-30"), by="days"), log_ret = rlnorm(181),indicator_1=1, indicator_k=0 )
```

### To achieve this I have tried the following:

#### Attempt One:

```
#(only pre-event window is included here)
DT1[, ":=" ('reg_pre_start' = Last.Day(RDt - month(6)),
            'reg_pre_end' = Last.Day(RDt - month(1)),
            'RDt_Dummy' = RDt)]
DT2[, 'Datadate_Dummy' := datadate] #Daily dates

setkey(DT1, gvkey, iid, reg_pre_start, reg_pre_end) #6 month interval
setkey(DT2, gvkey, iid, datadate, Datadate_Dummy) #Zero day interval


DT3 <- foverlaps(DT1, DT2, type='within', nomatch=0L)
```

#### Attempt Two:

I have additionally tried the following join:

```
DT3 <- DT1[DT2, on = c("gvkey", "iid", "reg_pre_start<=datadate", "reg_pre_end>=datadate"), .SD, by = .EACHI, nomatch = 0, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

Both are resulting on a merge table only on days RDt = datadate

I suspect the issue has something to do with the intervals being set in the non-traditional table

Comment: We're not going to be able to reproduce your random data, please start your code with `set.seed(42)` (or some other number).

Comment: Try copying `datadate` to another field (literal copy), and using it as a "range" (that is coincidentally zero-width). Then you can use whichever is "smaller" in the proper place for `foverlaps`.